# drawableLeft misaligns EditText only on phone

Tags: android, android-layout

In my project, I have `EditTexts` placed next to each other. In the IDE, it looks fine...

[image]

Yet after deploying it to my phone, the `EditText`with the drawable is misaligned

[image]

This only happens when adding `drawableLeft` and `drawableStart`. Note that the 2 sets of `EditTexts` are in their own `ConstraintLayout` which is in a horizontal `LinearLayout`, and only happens with the combination of `drawableLeft` and inside of the `LinearLayout`.

To replicate this problem. Simply create a new layout resource and deploy on your phone

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="2">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txt"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:singleLine="true"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txtDrawable"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_android_black_24dp"
                android:drawablePadding="8dp"
                android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_android_black_24dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:maxLength="4"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:singleLine="true"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

How can I align the `EditText` with the drawable to the adjacent `EditText`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the drawable is taking a larger height than the text height in the phone. Linear layout centers everything horizontally and that's why you are having this alignment problem. It is not necessary what you'll see in the IDE or in one phone you'll see exactly same thing in other devices. The may happen due to screen size and resolution.

On solution can be you can wrap all the edit texts in one constraint layout. Make the edit text with the drawable placed in center and rest of the edit text follow it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:singleLine="true"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/txtDrawable"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/txtDrawable"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtDrawable"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_android_black_24dp"
            android:drawablePadding="8dp"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_android_black_24dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:maxLength="4"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:singleLine="true"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/txt"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: The problem with that is I need the edit texts to have layout weight. Refer to the picture. I have 2 text boxes on the left that need to start at the left side, an the one with the drawable to start at the center

Comment: The drawable was, in fact, bigger than the edittext which helped me resolve my problem.

Comment: You can achieve the effects of weight with constraints. You can also set the gravity of linear layout to android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal" and get similar results. But remember according to the documentation constraint layout is efficient.